# Spot the error in experimenting with contradiction on 5's rationality.

Tags: proof-verification

Let $5=\frac ab$
$\forall\ a,b\ \epsilon\ N$. And $(a,b)=1$ 
Squaring both sides, 
$25b^2=a^2$ 
Thus, $25|a^2$; $25|a$ 
So $a=25m$ 
Substituting, $25b^2=25^2m^2$ 
So $b^2=25m^2$ 
So $25|b$ (By the same logic used before). 
But are assumption is proved to be wrong, because $25$ comes to be the common factor. So contradiction, proving that $5$ is not rational. So how is it possible?

Comment: Generally with fake proofs like this you should take a known counterexample and see where your proof fails. Clearly $a=5,b=1$ is a solution, so work from there and see where you come to a false conclusion. In this case, you see that the implication that if $25\mid a^2$, then $25\mid a$ is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you can't infer from 25 divides $a^2$ that 25 divides $a$.

Countereaxample: $a = 5$.

Answer (score 2):

If 25 divides $a^2$ all you can conclude is that $5$ divides $a.$